# How can we show Grand Summary of products price in product module listing in ConfigureIT admin or data panel

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, configureit

How can we show Grand Summary of product prices in product module listing in [Configure.IT](http://www.configure.it/platform/datapanel/) admin or data panel

Here I want to show grand summary of price at bottom of product module records listing as specified in below screenshot through Configure.IT admin or data panel module configuration, can anyone help?

[image]

Comment: Are you showing those products through `foreach` loop?

Comment: what is your code, you are using ci3 or ci2.x? this page is a shoping cart?

Comment: @Tpojka, I've not written the code, I'm using Configure.IT tool to create this listing, may be back-end is doing same `foreach` or `for`.

Comment: @elddenmedio, source code in ci3.x only, this page is in back-end admin panel

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Tpojka, thanks a lot, I'll will improve question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can achieve this using **Grand Summary** feature in module field settings.

To use it, go to settings of that field for which you want to calculate the grand summary and make grand summary **Yes** for it. Use **Sum** for group operation and provide **Grand Total : {0}** as grand text.

In Grand Total : {0}, **Grand total** is static data and **{0}** will be dynamic calculated value.

You can check it in below image too.

[image]

In output, this summary will display at the bottom of the grid like below image.

[image]

Try it once, may be it will helpful for you.